# Populating powershell array from XML

Tags: arrays, xml, powershell, join

I'm using Powershell 3.0 and Windows Server 2012

**Two arrays populated from an XML file:**

```
$a = @($Data.MessageGroup.Dataset[0].Series[1] | % {$_.Obs} | select TIME_PERIOD, OBS_VALUE)
$b = @($Data.MessageGroup.Dataset[0].Series[3] | % {$_.Obs} | select TIME_PERIOD, OBS_VALUE)
```

`$a` has 680 rows of date values in this format: `2015-09-30`
`$b` has 680 rows of values like: `3051.4`

I can list the elements from each array individually with no issues.
The problem is when I try to join the arrays.

Join the two arrays:

```
$c = $a, $b
```

`$c[0]` lists all of the dates;
`$c[1]` lists all of the values.
But when I try to join the two arrays it produces nothing.

```
$c[0]  -join " "
```

Comment: How end results should look like?

Comment: `$c  = @($a) + @($b)`

Comment: What I am looking for is this:
2015-08-31 3060.3
2015-09-30 3051.4

What the code from swestner presented produces this:
@{TIME_PERIOD=2015-08-31} @{OBS_VALUE=3060.3}

Answer (score 0):

would this work?

```
$a = @($Data.MessageGroup.Dataset[0].Series[1] | % {$_.Obs} | select TIME_PERIOD, OBS_VALUE)
$b = @($Data.MessageGroup.Dataset[0].Series[3] | % {$_.Obs} | select TIME_PERIOD, OBS_VALUE)
$i=0
$a | % {$_.TIME_PERIOD + " " + $b[$i++].OBS_VALUE}
```

For example

```
$a = @(1, 2, 3)
$b = @('a', 'b', 'c')
$i=0
$a | % {"$_ " + $b[$i++]}
```

Produces

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Comment: You should probably make your example look more XML-y to avoid it getting flagged or downvoted; it's not immediately obvious that it applies to the question.

Comment: Interestingly Your code produced the following:   @{TIME_PERIOD=2015-08-31} @{OBS_VALUE=3060.3}
@{TIME_PERIOD=2015-09-30} @{OBS_VALUE=3051.4}   I was expecting just the values from the arrays e.g. 2015-08-31  3060.3  2015-09-30  3051.4    Do I have to process the array differenly to get only the values?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the select. I will update the answer